# what is the meaning of "I work long hours"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What one means when he says I work long hours?

Does it mean that he works for many hours as I suspect?

Comment: Yes. The speaker works more hours at a time  than most people do, or that the speaker is accustomed to working. It refers to a habitual practice, unless a specific time period is mentioned, as in 'I work long hours this week', for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long hours is an idiom. If you work long hours, it means that you work for a period of time that is longer than the usual, regular, or routine for a given activity. In other words, it may mean overtime.

Here is the entry for this idiom on [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hours):

> long hours - A longer than usual or customary period of time for a given activity

The example follows: *worked long hours to finish the project on time.*